# "Общение" 2 компьютеров средствами c#

Tags: c#, связь

Появилась у меня надобность "связать" 2 компа, чтобы один мог отсылать какую-то информацию, а другой - читать ее и обрабатывать.

Сначала была идея с использованием БД, но постоянно слать туда запросы с целью проверки появления новых данных - не comme il faut.

Как лучше можно это реализовать? Куда смотреть? В каком направлении копать?

Comment: Да в принципе как угодно можно. Сервер на сокетах/[`TcpListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx), [named pipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx), [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Уточните что за данные, тогда можно будет дать совет конкретнее

Comment: Я бы в список возможных вариантов добавил RabbitMq, MSMQ, если есть потребность в durable.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk Ну, положим, массив байтов

Comment: Лично я поклонник [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd456779(v=vs.110).aspx) по двум основным причинам: нужно написать только код сервиса, код клиента генерируется автоматически; можно в любой момент легко добавлять привязки с разными протоколами передачи данных: TCP, HTTP, секурные (HTTPS), надёжные (MSMQ) и пр.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, почитал про TCP и WCF, все получилось)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov соглашусь с вами. Почитал про WCF, опробовал - действительно удобно)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Отлично! Может, тогда напишете ответ?